# Compute Canonical Cover

Tags: database

i was trying to compute canonical cover of

A → B C, C → A D, E → A B C, F → C D, C D → B E F, A B → D

I reduced it to

A → C, E → B, F → D, C → E F

But the answer is 
A → C, E → A B C, F → C D, C → E F

I am not sure if the given answer is right.

If the given answer is right , somebody please explain , why it cannot be reduced to 
A → C, E → B, F → D, C → E F

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1.A → B C, C → A D, E → A B C, F → C D, C D → B E F, A B → D

2 A → B C, C → A D, E → A B C, F → C D, C   → B E F, A B → D

3 A → B C, C → A B D E F, E → A B C, F → C D, A B → D

4 A → B C, C → A B D E F, E → A B C, F → C D, A   → D

5 A → B C D, C → A B D E F, E → A B C, F → C D

6 A → C D, C → A B D E F, E → A B C, F → C D

7 A → C, C → A B D E F, E → A B C, F → C D

8 A → C, C → B D E F, E → A B C, F → C D

9 A → C, C → D E F, E → A B C, F → C D

10 A → C, C → E F, E → A B C, F → C D

11 A → C, C → E F, E → A B, F → C D This is my answer, but your given answer is NO.10

Comment: i got it.the answer will be 10th one only.It cannot be 11th one because after removing the E->C , u will not get C in E's closure. So i think given answer is right